# Rewrite Rule 500 error issues Regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone give me an idea why this rewrite rule is causing me issues?

```
RewriteRule ^used-trucks/equipment/all/([^ ]*)-([^ \.]*)/(.*)? /inventory/?cat=equipment&make=$1\%20$2 [R=301,L]
```

I'm fairly new to this, I'd like i have some vars that come in like

```
 used-trucks/equipment/all/allis-chalmers/0012001
```

specifically

```
allis-chalmers
```

I'd like to convert them to this

```
 allis\%20chalmers
```

So they thru the reg ex variables would do the same as this

```
 /inventory/?cat=equipment&make=allis\%20chalmers
```

so they convert nicely in the redirect

Any help would be appriciated! thanks =)

Comment: Is the redirect not occurring? Would help if you were a little more specific. Try changing your rule to this: `RewriteRule ^used-trucks/equipment/all/([^\s]+)-([^\s\.]+)/(.*)? /inventory/?cat=equipment&make=$1\%20$2 [R=301,L]`. If that doesn't work, please update your question with the entire content of your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your spaces. Apache isn't very clever about how it parses its directives so when it sees a space, even if it's inside a regular expression, it uses it as a delimiter between parameters.

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^used-trucks/equipment/all/([^\ ]*)-([^\ \.]*)/(.*)? /inventory/?cat=equipment&make=$1\%20$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That kinda working the way i want it to but now its doing this if i use
      new-holland i get new%2520holland

Comment: Perhaps you could use `$1+$2` instead?

Comment: @AlexBloom Try adding a `NE` flag to your square brackets to prevent the "%" from getting encoded

Comment: Thank you guys between all of you that got me where i wanted it to go